# Sequence number not showing

Tags: trigger

Requirment is when i have to save new contact it'll show the sequence number. example if i have 3 contact in org and then i have added another one then in sequence field it will show 4 value.

Trigger-------------

```
 Trigger contactTrigger on Contact(before insert) {

 if(Trigger.isInsert){
    contSeque.Seq(trigger.new);
   } }
```

---

```
public class contSeque {  

public static void Seq(List<Contact> conList){
    if(conList.size()>0){
            List <AggregateResult> req = [select count(Id) cout from contact]; 
            for(AggregateResult obj : requirements){

                Contact c = new Contact();
                Decimal count = (Decimal)obj.get('cout')+1;
                c.Sequence__c = count;
            } 
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like your class would even compile at the moment. You might also want to consider what would happen if two contacts were created at the same time by different users....might you end up with a duplicate sequence?

Comment: Why would you write code for this? There is a field type called Auto Number for this purpose.

Comment: Adition to @PhilHawthorn's point, you will need to take care of the contacts deletion scenario. Delete will result in lowering the count, where the sequence series will remain unchanged and will result in duplicate sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to modify your handler class as it does not look like it would compile:

```
public class contSeque {  

    public static void Seq(List<Contact> conList){
        if(conList.size()>0){
            integer count = database.countQuery('select count() from contact');
            for(Contact c : conList){                   
                c.Sequence__c = count;
            } 
        }
     }
 }
```

However, why not just use an Auto Number type field? If you have more granular requirements (i.e. one sequence across all contacts is not satisfactory) you would also need to consider duplicates.